# check if a list has ascending elements - descending elements or descending elements - ascending elements

Tags: haskell

I'm beginner in Haskell. I have found a problem in a book: Check if a list has aspect of a "mountain", ascending elements - descending elements. Check if a list has aspect of a "valley",descending elements - ascending elements.Please help me.

Exemple:

"Mountain": [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1]

"Valley": [4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4]

My code looks:

1. Mountain

   ```
   ordered::[Int]->Bool
   ordered [a]=True
   ordered (a:l)=if(a>head(l)) then False
             else ordered(l)
   ```
2. Valley

   ```
   ordered::[Int]->Bool
   ordered [a]=True
   ordered (a:l)=if(a<head(l)) then False
             else ordered(l)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a strategy: a list is a "mountain" if it has only one [local maximum](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/functions-maxima-minima.html) once you remove adjacent repeated elements. Likewise, a "valley" is a list that has only one local minimum once adjacent repeated elements are removed. The functions below will tell if a list is a mountain or a valley:

```
isMountain :: [Integer] -> Bool
isMountain xs = 1 == (length $ localMaxima $ rmAdjacentDups xs)

isValley :: [Integer] -> Bool
isValley xs = 1 == (length $ localMinima $ rmAdjacentDups xs)

*Main> isMountain [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1]
True
*Main> isMountain [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,3,2,1]
False
*Main> isValley [4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4]
True
*Main> isValley [4,3,2,1,2,1,1,2,3,4]
False
```

Leave a comment if you're stuck implementing `localMaxima`, `localMinima` or `rmAdjacentDups`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I made the changes below,  but i don't really know how to solve this error:  Type error in application
*** Expression     : lung $ localMinima $ rmAdjacentDups xs
*** Term           : lung
*** Type           : [Integer] -> Integer
*** Does not match : Integer -> Integer

Answer (score 2):

You should start by thinking about the base case. You've started with a base case of a list with 1 element, but there's a simpler base case: the empty list. The empty list is normally considered to be *both* ascending *and* descending. The next thing you should do is to quit using `head`. It's partial, and will lead you into errors. Instead, pattern match everything.

Hint on writing a really simple version, after you write the pattern-matching one: use `zipWith` and `drop`. Note that unlike `tail`, `drop` is a total function.

Comment: Thank you very much. At this moment, I don't really know how to work with drop, zip Width. For now, I choose to resolve the problem recursively.

Answer (score 1):

```
localMinima :: [Integer] -> Integer
localMinima [x]=x
localMinima (x:xs) = if x<m then x
                 else m where m=localMinima xs


rmAdjacentDups :: [Integer]->[Integer]
rmAdjacentDups []     = []
rmAdjacentDups (x:xs) = x : (rmAdjacentDups $ dropWhile (== x) xs)


isValley :: [Integer] -> Bool
isValley xs = 1 == (length $ localMinima $ rmAdjacentDups xs)
```

Comment: A local minimum of a list is an element of the list which is strictly smaller than both the elements immediately before and after it. For example, in the list `[4, 3, 5, 4, 1]`, the only local minimum is `3`, since it is smaller than the elements immediately before and after it (`4`and `5`). `1` is not a local minimum since there is no element that comes after it. Hence `localMinima [1]` shouldn't return `1` because there is no element that comes before nor after it. Also `localMinima` should return `[Integer]` because there can be more than one local minima in a list.

Comment: Give a shot at [HSpec](http://hspec.github.io/) to test your functions. For example, once `localMinima` pass your tests, then you can forget about it and move to `rmAdjacentDups`.